# Azure DevOps - widgets sizes

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm using Azure DevOps dashboards. Is there any way to resize one of the default widgets? I am looking for a way to resize 'Release Pipeline Overview' widget over standard options provided in configuration tab.

Here is some description about mentioned widget:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#release-pipeline-overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> resize 'Release Pipeline Overview' widget over standard options
>   provided in configuration tab.

For this issue , you can do it through [Update Widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/dashboard/widgets/update%20widget?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples) rest api:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{dashboardId}/widgets/{widgetId}?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

Sample request body:

```
{
    "id": "456afb86-ecf6-49cf-bbcc-1ab7d0fc14b2",
    "eTag": "1",
    "name": "Release Pipeline Overview",

    "size": {
        "rowSpan": 4,
        "columnSpan": 4
    },
    "settings": "{\"releaseDefinitionId\":1}",
    "settingsVersion": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 0,
        "patch": 0
    },
    "dashboard": {
    "eTag": "6"
    },

    "contributionId": "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-definition-summary-widget"
}
```

You can customize the size in the request body.

Here is my test with postman and the result in dashboard:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check my msg below

Comment: @Rob Ert Hi,currently, resize the content is not supported. You could submit this feature request  in our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site.Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.

Comment: @Rob Ert If my answer is helpful to you ,could you [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread and we could archive this thread, thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answer that's cool! And it's almost working as I want. 
That's true widget size has been changed but content inside still have the same limitations. Any idea how to overcome this one?

[image]

Comment: Err I have submitted a request  in our user voice site. You can comment and vote [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/771343/resize-the-content-inside-widget.html) to increase the priority of this user voice.